# Proof of exponential theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am currently reading Joseph Edwards' differential​ calculus for beginners. I am a beginner, in am in 10th. 
$$a^x = 1 + x\ln a + \frac{x^2}{2!} (\ln a)^2 + \frac{x^3}{3!} (\ln a)^3...$$ I know it makes sense because if you plug in $e=a$ you get the maclaurin expansion for $e^x$. But what about a rigorous proof. I have tried messing around with it. I can't see a connection for natural logs be appearing in an exponent like $a^x$ without $e$ being in it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you assume there exists a real number $e$ such that $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is true ? In that case it reduces to show there exists $b= \ln a$ such that $e^b = a$, then show $e^{b x} = (e^b)^x$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
a^x=e^{x\ln a}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k(\ln a)^k}{k!}
$$
where the second equality comes from knowledge of the Maclaurin series for $e^x$

Answer (score 1):

The following is largely based on and expanded from Articles 149 through 154 of *A Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics*.

First, expand $a^{x}=\left\{ 1+\left(a-1\right)\right\}^{x}$ by binomial theorem as $$
a^{x} =1+\left(a-1\right)x+\frac{x\left(x-1\right)}{2!}\left(a-1\right)^{2}+\frac{x\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)}{3!}\left(a-1\right)^{3}+\cdots
$$
Define $c_i$ as the coefficient for $x^i$ so that we can rewrite it as
$$
a^{x}=1+c_{1}x+c_{2}x^{2}+c_{3}x^{3}+\cdots
$$
For the value of $c_1$, if we collect all coefficients of $x$, we get
$$\begin{align}
c_1 &=\left(a-1\right)+\frac{-1}{2!}\left(a-1\right)^{2}+\frac{\left(-1\right)\left(-2\right)}{3!}\left(a-1\right)^{3}+\frac{\left(-1\right)\left(-2\right)\left(-3\right)}{4!}\left(a-1\right)^{4}+\cdots\\
 &=\left(a-1\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(a-1\right)^{2}+\frac{2!}{3!}\left(a-1\right)^{3}-\frac{3!}{4!}\left(a-1\right)^{4}+\cdots\\
 &=\left(a-1\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(a-1\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(a-1\right)^{3}-\frac{1}{4}\left(a-1\right)^{4}+\cdots\\
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, for $a^y$ and $a^{x+y}$, we have
$$\begin{align}
a^{y} &=1+c_{1}y+c_{2}y^{2}+c_{3}y^{3}+\cdots,\text{ and}\\
a^{x+y} &=1+c_{1}\left(x+y\right)+c_{2}\left(x+y\right)^{2}+c_{3}\left(x+y\right)^{3}+\cdots.\\
\end{align}
$$
Because $a^x \cdot a^y = a^{x+y}$, the coefficients from multiplying the series expansions of $a^x$ and of $a^y$ should match those of $a^{x+y}$. In the multiplication of the expansions, the $xy^{i}$ term has coefficient $$c_{1}c_{i}.$$
But in the $a^{x+y}$ expansion, the corresponding $xy^{i}$ term only comes from $c_{i+1}\left(x+y\right)^{i+1}$ with coefficient
$$
c_{i+1}\tbinom{i+1}{1}=\left(i+1\right)c_{i+1}.
$$
Therefore, by matching the above two coefficients,
$$c_{1}c_{i}=\left(i+1\right)c_{i+1}\ \forall\ i.$$
This established a recurrence relation in the $c_{i}$ values.

To obtain the $n$th coefficient $c_{n}$, we can multiply such identities together to get
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(c_{1}c_{i}\right) &=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(i+1\right)c_{i+1},\\
c^{n-1}\cdot c\cdot {\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}c_{i}} &=n!\cdot c_{n}\cdot{\prod_{j=2}^{n-1}c_{j}}\ ,\\
 c^{n} &=n!c_{n}.\\
\end{align}
$$
In other words, $c_n=\tfrac{c^n}{n!}$ and
$$
a^x=1+c_1 x + \frac{c_1^2}{2!}x^2 +\frac{c_1^3}{3!}x^3+\cdots
$$
It remains to show that $c_1=\ln a$.

Let $e$ be the value of $a$ such that $c_1=1$, then
$$
e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$
If we choose $x=1$ in the $a^x$ expansion, then
$$
a=1+c_1  + \frac{c_1^2}{2!} +\frac{c_1^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$
If we choose $x=c_1$ in $e^x$ expansion,
$$
e^{c_1} = 1 + {c_1} + \frac{{c_1}^2}{2!} + \frac{{c_1}^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$
By comparing the above two series, we see that $a=e^{c_1}$ and thus $c_1=\ln a$. This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the Taylor's expansion for $a^x$ since $(a^x)'=a^x\log a$, $(a^x)''=a^x\log^2 a$ and so on.

**Note**

$$a^x = e^{x\ln{a}}\implies (a^x)'=(e^{x\ln{a}})'=e^{x\ln{a}}\ln a=a^x \ln a$$

Comment: How do you evaluate the derivative of $a^x$ without using E..T

Comment: @user167920 it's a matter of derivation rules, you can find the proof in every book

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^x = y$.
$x \ln a = \ln y$
$e^{x\ln a}= y$

$\therefore a^x = e^{x\ln a}$
$a^x = {(e^x) }^{\ln a}$
$a^{\frac {x}{\ln a}} = e^x $
Substituting $a^{\frac {x}{\ln a}} = e^x$ into the Maclaurin expansion for $e^x$ should give you the same expansion as your original one.
(**Note:** this may be wrong so please pardon me. I am also in the $10^{th}$ grade and I am *supposed* to learn this after $2$ years).

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor series we have: 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

with $f(x)= a^x =e^{x\ln a}$ see that

$$f'(x) =\ln a ~e^{x\ln a}= \ln a\cdot f(x),~~f^{(2)}(x)= (\ln a)^{2} f(x)\cdots\cdots , f^{(n)}(x)= (\ln a)^{n} f(x)$$

that is $$f(0) =1,~~f'(0) =\ln a ,~~f^{(2)}(0)= (\ln a)^{2} \cdots\cdots , f^{(n)}(0)= (\ln a)^{n} $$